# What is [this] in C++/CX? (Windows 8)

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-8, c++-cx

I'm following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465045.aspx) guide, and I'm hitting these parts of the code that include the term `[this]` (Just Ctrl-F it; you'll see what I mean).

I'm not sure if this is a C++ thing or a C++/CX thing, but, either way, I don't know what it is.

What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a "Lambda Closure" and it's saying that the current instance (`this`) is to be passed into the lambda body (enabling you to use it's variables, and call it's methods).

This page gives a good summary of Lambda Closures:
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

> []        Capture nothing (or, a scorched earth strategy?)
>   [&]       Capture any referenced variable by reference
>   [=]       Capture any referenced variable by making a copy
>   [=, &foo] Capture any referenced variable by making a copy, but capture variable foo by reference
>   [bar]     Capture bar by making a copy; don't copy anything else
>   [this]    Capture the this pointer of the enclosing class

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What exactly is the lambda body? There's a scope, but the syntax is really messing with my head.

create_task(feedOp).then([this] (SyndicationFeed^ feed) -> SyndicationFeed^
 { . . .}

<-- Referring to that particular piece of code.

Comment: What is the lambda body? It's just an anonymous function.

Comment: Basically the lambda body will be called back when the asynchronous operation (feedOp) finishes.

Answer (score 3):

It is syntax for a [lambda anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B) that captures the members of the class where it is defined. It is C++11.